Water well tank has no air pressure and unable to pump any air
I have this water well 2 gal inline tank. The water pump seems to be cycling, so I want to check the air pressure in the tank.
I press the Shrader,#1 on image, valve and no air comes out. I tried to pump air into it, and there is no air flow into the tank. The bike pump has tons of resistance. I even replaced the valve.
Why am I not be able to pump any air into the tank?
The tank is probably done, correct?

Also, what is the purpose of this lower valve #2 on image?

the air valve would look like the car tire valve

I have put air in many air valves(tires/tanks) with quite a few air pumps.  There is usually there is that one valve that does not like the pump valve, sometimes just need to press down much harder.  A bad seal/diafram in the tank should let water out of the air valve on top.

with the valve core removed (you said you replaced it)  are you able to pump any air, (I do not expect the air to stay in with no valve core, but I do expect it to flow)

Are you sure the tank isn't waterlogged and 100% full of water, which would prevent any air from getting injected?

Yes, I removed the valve, and I was not able to pump any air either, which left me perplexed. I will check the waterlogged issue.   Thanks

@Milwrdfan The tank was water logged. I replaced it with a new tank with the same specs, and the cycling stopped. Thanks, add your comment as an answer, and I will mark it as so.

Check to make sure your tank bladder hasn't failed and your tank is full of water.  If the tank is already completely full of water (i.e. waterlogged), you won't be able to add any air to the tank, no matter how hard you try.

Yes, this was my problem. I replaced the tank. Thanks!

It's likely that your pump has a sub-standard length pin-depressor or it is faulty/damaged. If you've replaced the internal valve, you've narrowed things down to factors outside of the tank. This is consistent with your description of excessive back pressure. Double check your pump on a bicycle tire or similar, especially something of smaller volume to better see the results.
There are right-angle adapters for tire valves as well as extenders. These may have a longer center pin and some terminate at the "user" end with a ball type valve that would be more likely to be depressed by your pump. Amazon is one of many sources, image below from linked site:

This is also the type of item that is best used when needed and removed when not in use, as it's yet another interface to generate complications.

The pump works well with cars and bicycle valves. I also adjusted the water tank valve, so it is not too deep, and the pump can easily depress the pin.  I finally removed the valve completely, and I was not able to pump any air, so I figure this tank is full with water. Perhaps the diaphragm is pushed up by water.
